# What happens if a Cognito Form cannot connect to SharePoint?

Tags: cognito-forms, sharepoint

We would like to connect our Cognito Forms to our local SharePoint system. In the scenario that our SharePoint system becomes unavailable, will Cognito Forms attempt to re-send the data at a later time if a successful connection is not made?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with Cognito Forms. Unfortunately, Cognito Forms will not re-send the data if the SharePoint system is down when the integration is triggered. However, Cognito Forms does provide a way to re-submit an entry. In order to do this, you will need to enable "Save & Resume" on your form. Once "Save & Resume" is enabled, you will be able to set the status of an entry to "Incomplete" on the Entries page. When you edit an "Incomplete" entry, you will have the option to "Submit" the entry. Please keep in mind that all notifications or integration configured to run when an entry is submitted will be triggered. For example, a email notification configured to be sent when an entry is submitted will go out.